# Swift UITableview custom cell Imageview color change in another function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My scenario, I am trying to change `UITableview` Custom Cell Imageview Image color based on my theme. Here, I need to access UITableview Custom Cell  `Imageview` in another function without passing Indexrow and sender. I used below code but tableview custom cell image color not changing.

Below My Code

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.themeValidation(theme:"1")
    }

    func themeValidation(theme:String){

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomCell 

            // Validation based on color name
            switch theme {
            case "1" :
                cell.Icon.image = UIImage(named: "pic") 
                cell.Icon.setImageColors(color:  UIColor.blue) // Here not working
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blue
                break
            case "2" :
                cell.dateIcon.image = UIImage(named: "pic") // Here not working
                cell.Icon.setImageColors(color:  UIColor.red) 
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
                break
            case "3" :
                cell.Icon.image = UIImage(named: "pic")
                cell.Icon.setImageColors(color:  UIColor.green) // Here not working
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.green
                break
            default:
                print("Default")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you call `tableView.dequeueReusableCell`, that creates a new cell. You should call `themeValidation` from inside `cellForRow` instead of `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: But I am changing navigation bar color and another some UI color also within Switch Case. If I call from cellForRow it will change every time? Please provide some sample @DávidPásztor

Comment: save theme as global variable and use it in cellForRow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `tableView.dequeueReusableCell`, that creates a new cell. You need to pass in the actual cell (or at least its `IndexPath` to be able to access the cell from the `tableView`.

You should break up your theming function into a separate one for table view cells, which you'll call from `cellForRowAt` and another one, which you'll call from `viewWillAppear`.

Some further improvements: you should always use an `enum` when you have a finite and immutable set of values that a certain thing can get a value from, specifically `Theme` in your case.

```
enum Theme {
    case blue
    case red
    case green

    var themeColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .blue:
            return .blue
        case .red:
            return .red
        case .green:
            return .green
        }
    }
}

class VC: UITableViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        setGlobalTheme(to: .blue)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        setTheme(for: cell, to: .blue)
        return cell
    }

    func setGlobalTheme(to theme: Theme) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = theme.themeColor
    }

    func setTheme(for cell: CustomCell, to theme: Theme) {
        cell.Icon.image = UIImage(named: "pic")
        cell.Icon.setImageColors(color: theme.themeColor)
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to change the theme and then apply those changes to your cells, you either need to call `tableView.reloadData` after you changed the theme or even better, define below function, which iterates through all visible cells and updates them.

```
func changeTheme(to theme: Theme) {
    setGlobalTheme(to: theme)
    tableView.visibleCells.forEach {
        guard let customCell = $0 as? CustomCell else { return }
        setTheme(for: customCell, to: theme)
    }
}
```

Just make sure to call `changeTheme(to:)` when you want to update the theme.

Comment: Thanks you. I will check and update here. @David Pasztor

Comment: This is a more elegant way than my answer. If you want to implement something like this through out your app, creating a theme manager, and reading your theme from there would be a better Idea, for a quick fix, you can refer my answer :-p Happy coding

Comment: If I change the value tableview not updating @David Pasztor

Comment: @BenDev you need to call `tableView.reloadData` after you change the theme. Or for an even better solution, check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

call below method just right before you call delegate and dataSource for tableView may be in ViewDidLaod example like below.

```
self.themeValidation(theme:"1")
tableView.delegate=self
tableView.dataSource=self
```

**OR**

You may put a color in default case too so if it not find any theme it should set color from your default case

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do.

Create a variable for theme

```
var theme:String
```

then on **viewWillApear**, or wherever you set your theme, set this variable and call your theme update method

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.theme = "1"
    self.themeValidation()
}
```

And your themeValidation method will look like this

```
func themeValidation(theme:String){
//Only for view related changes and not cell related changes
    switch self.theme {
        case "1": //Do your changes related to view here
        case "2": //Do your changes related to view here

    }
}
```

And now in you **cellForRow** method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomCell 
    switch self.theme {
        case "1":
        cell.Icon.image = UIImage(named: "pic") 
        cell.Icon.setImageColors(color:  UIColor.blue)
        case "2":
        cell.Icon.setImageColors(color:  UIColor.red) 
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```